# C# Code on TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider gives a different value from cryptojs

Tags: javascript, c#, cryptojs

I am trying to transpose a c# code to a javascript using cryptojs and in the c# code it uses TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider. I can get everything exactly the values of C# in my javascript code except for the encrypting part. I get a different result on the encryption.
Please see my code on c# and javascript.

C#
public static string EncryptTxt(string key, string msg, CipherMode mode, Int16 KeyOffSet)
{
    SHA512CryptoServiceProvider sha = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] newKey = new byte[23];

```
using (var tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    byte[] Results;
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] keybyte = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    byte[] newKeyx = new byte[24];

    Array.Copy(keybyte, KeyOffSet, newKeyx, 0, newKeyx.Length);

    TDESAlgorithm.Key = newKeyx;
    TDESAlgorithm.Mode = mode;
    TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    byte[] DataToEncrypt = UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
    try
    {
        ICryptoTransform Encryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
        Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length);
    }
finally
{
    TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
    HashProvider.Clear();
}
return Convert.ToBase64String(Results);
```

}

javascript

```
encryptText = () => {
    debugger;
    const msg = 'Autosweep2Go1:juan:201910181809:12345678';
    let key = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse('xxx');
    key = crypto.MD5(key);
    key.words.push(key.words[0], key.words[1]);
    const iv = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse('xxx');

    // MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    const hashProvider = crypto.MD5(iv);
    const TDESKey = this.wordArrayToByteArray(hashProvider, 8);

    const keybyte = this.wordArrayToByteArray(crypto.SHA512(iv), 16);
    const newKeyx = new Uint8Array(24);

    const newkeybyte = keybyte.slice(10, 34);
    // Object.assign(newKeyx, newkeybyte);

    const TDESAlgorithmKey = newkeybyte;
    const DataToEncrypt = this.wordArrayToByteArray(crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(msg), 40);
    const dteLength = DataToEncrypt.length;
    const encrypted = crypto.TripleDES.encrypt(crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(msg),
    crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(newkeybyte),
    {
      mode: crypto.mode.ECB,
      padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7,
    });
    const result = this.wordArrayToByteArray(encrypted.ciphertext, dteLength);
    const x = this.wordArrayToByteArray(crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(encrypted.toString()), dteLength);

    console.log(encrypted);
    return encrypted;
     }
```

C# Result

[image]

Javasctipt Result

[image]

Can you please show me how to do this right. I really appreciate it!

Comment: IV doesn't exist in your C# code, though it all appears to be a bit weird in that you're defining multiple variables (key and iv) but only using one of them.

Comment: am just interchanging them for debugging reasons. I am going to clean the code as soon as I get to work. the IV and the Key are the same the way i understand it. RIght?

Comment: _"The IV and the Key are the same the way i understand it."_ - No, IV is (kind of) to encryption what salt is to hashing. See [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35210/encrypting-using-aes-256-do-i-need-iv) about IV for more info.